# Smooth scrolling anchor $ not defined

Tags: jquery, html

Jquery smooth scroll not working for my code. It jumps to the correct place, but does not scroll smoothly. Below is my codepen I have created, can anyone figure out what is wrong with it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BdKvva

Thanks

Comment: works for me https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKNVWZ

Comment: You need to add jquery.js Try after adding https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js to settings in javascript of codepen

Comment: Thanks - what does this mean:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: @RA19 you need jquery library to run smooth scroll